# BoncyCastle exception org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ElGamalPublicKeySpec

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle

Need help on this issue. It is happening in Jboss server (Unix), Java 8 while doing encyption. Even i put the jars bcpg-jdk15-1.45.jar,bcprov-jdk15-1.45.jar jre/lib/ext added 
entry in java.security file

```
security.provider.10=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

Below is the error

```
 java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Unknown KeySpec type: org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ElGamalPublicKeySpec
        at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source) [_RestorationHardware.CreditCardRefresher_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyFactory$ElGamal.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source) [_RestorationHardware.CreditCardRefresher_slib_sclasses.jar:]
        at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:328) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
        at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKey.getKey(PGPPublicKey.java:536) [_RestorationHardware.CreditCardRefresher_slib_sclasses.jar:]
```

Not sure what i am missing here. Followed this also
http://www.bouncycastle.org/jira/browse/BJA-389?jql=text%20~%20%22ElGamalPublicKeySpec%22
but it didn't worked out

Comment: You haven't by any chance (de-) serialized the key spec, right? That's a weird error, and your provider clearly has been registered, otherwise it would not use the JDKKeyFactory. Having two incompatible .jar files might also cause these kind of issues (one in ext and one for your application, for instance).

Comment: When i update BC jar to 1.47 its working...dont know why there is issue with 1.45

Comment: Bouncy Castle is now at 1.59. I would strongly recommend that you keep an update scheme for security relevant libraries. Note that Java 9 should also contain updates wrt Diffie Hellman, you may want to have a look how everything runs under Java 9 without Bouncy Castle. Note that BC is software only and may miss some enhancements when it comes to CPU / native code.

Comment: You were right, it is because of two jar, one in lib/ext and one in application...Now its resolved thanks a lot :D